# Trying to design and implement database

Tags: database-design, azure

I'm in the preliminary stages of developing a design for the database.

Here is my dilemma:
I've currently outlined roughly 150+ fields that will need to be inputted inside the database but I'm having difficulty deciding how to break up the fields into effective tables linked together, which follows regular normalization rules.

Just to give you a snippet of the information I'm collecting on a single soldier:

- Personal Information (name, regimental number, religion, place of birth, next of kin etc.)
- Family Members (parents, children, siblings)
- Education History (age when left school, highest grade level reached, college/university, trades/apprenticehip, languages spoken/written etc.)
- Occupational History (prior work experience, name of employer, specific occupation, work guaranteed after discharge, farming experience etc.)
- Medical History (Age, Eye/Hair Colour, Height, Weight, Complexion, Scars, Vision, Hearing etc.)
- Medical Examination (Broken Bone History, Previous head injuries-spinal trouble-ruptures-tuberculosis-asthma, blood pressure, many other conditions etc.)
- Regimental History (date of enlistment, regiment at time of enlistment, other regiments joined, highest rank etc.)
- Locations of Soldier (a list of all important locations a soldier has been from birth, enlistment, training, battlefields, death)
- Burial Info (date of death, place of death, cemetery, grave site etc.)

Clearly, there is a ton of information that needs to be collected on a single soldier. My problem is trying to decide how to split up the tables in a manageable and efficient method, and also the primary/foreign keys that need to be listed for each one.

1. It seems illogical to think that there would be one massive table where each row would be a soldier.
2. Logistically, maybe I should break up the database into the tables as listed above but then I wouldn't know what to use for the primary keys because it would be roughly the same soldierID for each row - that would then connect the tables together (that doesn't seem right to me because isn't it the same as #1?)
3. Break up the database into very simplistic tables (i.e. a couple of columns per table) that point to each other. Example: Language_Table which has a list of all languages possibly spoken/written each with a unique id. This seems like it makes the most sense but would create a massive number of tables.

The plan is also to host the database on Azure which will eventually feed into a Windows Phone App.

Comment: You don't have to force your data into a relational database. An alternative approach is to have a single field `SoldierInformation` which contains an XML or JSON string that contains all the information you have above. Or, even better, you could look at a NoSQL database such as MongoDB which can be very well suited for this sort of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) the information for a soldier.  Reading the Wikipedia article that I linked is about a concise an explanation as I can provide.  By normalizing the relationship of the data items, you can store this information in a relational database.

Let's start with a Soldier table.  Generally, table names are singular and start with a capital letter.  You would put every item in this table where the soldier had **one and only one occurrence** of this item.

Some items that fit this criteria would be: name, place of birth, date of birth, date of death, place of death, burial site, etc.

This table can have as many items (columns) as you need. The only criteria is that each item occurs one time.

So, what happens with a soldier has more than one of something?

Let's take family members as an example.  A FamilyMember table could look something like this:

```
FamilyMember
------------
FamilyMemberID
SoldierID
FamilyMemberType
FamilyMemberName
...
```

The FamilyMemberID is the primary (clustering) key of the FamilyMember table.  It's an auto-incrementing integer or long that provides a unique key to the table.

The SoldierID is a foreign key back to the Soldier table.

The FamilyMemberType describes the relationship between the family member and the soldier.  Some examples would be parent, brother, sister, etc.  Usually, you would save a code (P for parent, B for brother, S for sister) rather than the text.

The remainder of the columns describe the family member.  These columns represent **one and only one occurrence** of a family member.

You do this for all of the data items that you want to save in a relational database.

For every item, you ask yourself, *what is the relationship between a soldier and this item?*

To take one more example, let's look a regiment.  What is the relationship between a soldier and a regiment?  A soldier can belong to one or more regiments.

So, your Regiment table would be structured similarly to the FamilyMember table.

Answer (score 1):

Not wanting to throw too much of a curveball but have you considered using a document database instead, something like RavenDb? It would allow you to easily hold all of this information in a single document, because it all relates to a single soldier so it feels fairly arbitrary to try and split it into related tables. It's all metadata relating to a soldier, so store it together against a single soldier record.

As a first step, I would concentrate on designing your domain model to accurately map the data that you wish to record about the solider as detailed in your question. Once you have done that, think about how to map it to your chosen data store.

Answer (score 0):

I can maybe give you a tip... the comment given is maybe not so bad for you but you could decide de create a real database too. You problem is that the information concerns specifically a soldier... nevertheless you can cut the information if you can see self-sufficient information(like it would be when you try to find the object that could be evolved from reading specifications).

In your database there would be quite a lot of referentiel tables... I give you examples :

a Religion table with all the religion known this days and a link from this table to the Soldier Table. (the good thing is that in your soldier table christian is always Christian and not once christian, cristian or kristian..)

Then you have to find this paticular objects :
example : WORK

You could add a Work Table with Name of the employee, start date, end date ....

or MEDICAL FILE:
consultation date, hospital (referential by the way), height, weight,....

Something like that